# How do I use callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am adding following piece of javascript but I dont want to mess up the original intention of the onclick function (which is to add an item to sharepoint list).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    element.removeEventListener('click',redirect(),false)
    function redirect()
    {
      var inputcCtrls = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for(m=0; m<inputcCtrls.length; m++){  
           if(inputcCtrls[m].type == 'button' && inputcCtrls[m].value == 'Finish'){        
                              window.parent.location = "http://intranet/surveys/Pages/ThankYou.aspx";  window.close();
}}}
    </script>
```

Comment: You can use `addEventListener` and `attachEvent`. More about that can be found at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
element.removeEventListener('click',redirect(),false)
function redirect()
{  var inputcCtrls = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(m=0; m<inputcCtrls.length; m++){  
       if(inputcCtrls[m].type == 'button' && inputcCtrls[m].value == 'Finish'){        
window.parent.location = "http://intranet/surveys/Pages/ThankYou.aspx";  window.close();
}}}
</script>
I tried this and now I can add an item to the list but It does not open the thankyou page.

Comment: Your code is wrong. But I actually don't understand what you are really trying to do, so I cannot help you nay further.

Comment: I am working on a Survey List in SharePoint. SP gives you a submit button called "Finish". When user clicks on Finish button it adds an item to the survey list. I need to add additional function so that users are redirected to a thankyou page.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you have one button you want to bind the function `funcOnClick` to.

You can add an ID to that button called **redirect**, then do something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function(){
     var button = document.getElementById('redirect');
     button.onclick = funcOnClick;
 }
</script>

<button id="redirect">Finish</button>
```

Comment: Actually the button "Finish" is a sharepoint button that adds an item to survey list. I am trying to add addional function either to that button or after a user has clicked that button so that I can redirect them to thankyou page.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Mmh. I forgot that the order in which the event handlers are executed is not guaranteed. Try this (`redirect` like below):

```
var inputcCtrls = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
for(m=0; m<inputcCtrls.length; m++){ 
    if(inputcCtrls[m].type == 'button' && inputcCtrls[m].value == 'Finish'){
        var input = inputcCtrls[m];
        var __orig_handler = input.onclick;
        input.onclick = function() {
            __orig_handler();
            redirect();
        };
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Ok, maybe this is what you want:

```
function redirect() { 
    window.parent.location = "intranet/surveys/Pages/ThankYou.aspx";
}

var inputcCtrls = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
for(m=0; m<inputcCtrls.length; m++){ 
    if(inputcCtrls[m].type == 'button' && inputcCtrls[m].value == 'Finish'){
        inputcCtrls[m].addEventListener('click', redirect, false);
        break;
    }
}
```

Notice that you have to use `attachEvent` and `onclick` for IE.

Comment: your code redirects to the thankyou page and bypasses "Finish" original events. (How to I add attachEvent with your code)?

Comment: Hi felix. the original function of the "Finish" button is working (adding a record in survey list). redirect piece still not working.

Comment: Actually there was an error in code, `:` instead of `;` after `redirect`. Does it work when you fix this?

Comment: Yes sir, I have fixed the ; issue. But still the same problem.

Comment: Well, then I don't know. I don't the environment and I don't know SharePoint actually. I also don't know what *else* the click handler is doing.